# how can i change the URL default in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I change the url('/') default value in Laravel 5.2?

I tried changing it on config/app.php and .env but still doesnt work.

```
// 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

Comment: the default is http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but i like to try it like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/mrvince/ without using echo url('/mrvince/') in view;

Comment: You could use redirect to your `url` when someone hits your '/'.

Comment: is that the proper way in laravel sir?

Comment: Yes that is the proper way to do. Have a look at this docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a snippet from the `app.php`:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

This tells that this url is only used for the local artisan task.

But you are trying to redirect your `home route` to something like `mrvince`, which clearly states that you will be changing the url when a user arrives to your home route.

Your purpose to change the `url` is different i.e. you always might want to change the home route to something other but if you get succeed on changing the url, it will not work for production purpose as you will not use `Artisan server` in `production`.

So, i prefer to redirect the request to some other place if needed like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('profile');
});

Route::get('profile', [
    'as' => 'profile',
    'uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod'
]);
```

Also have a look at this docs:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

Hope this helps. If i am not correct could anyone correct me in this scenario.